# When should EnableViewState be enabled on a server control?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any guideline or rule for when the **view state** should be enabled on a server control? And when it should ***not***?

I was looking at this [`SqlDatasource` example](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/data/GridViewMasterDetailsInsert.src) and noticed that the view state for the label control is not enabled:

```xml
<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessageLabel" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" />
```

Why isn't `EnableViewState` enabled on the label control? I know that enabling the view state carries some overhead so I would like to use it only when it is needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a good rule of thumb:  If you (1) change a property's value in the code-behind, and  (2) need to know what value you set in a later postback without recalculating the value, then you need to use ViewState.

For example.  In my page's markup I might have a Label control specified like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text="Update this Employee" />
```

Then in the Page_Load event I have this code:

```
If Not IsPostBack AndAlso myEmployeeObject.IsNew Then TitleLabel.Text = "Create a new Employee"
```

By changing the value of the Text property, I've introduced a new element into ViewState.  If I get the value of the Label's Text property during any subsequent PostBack, the value will be "Create a new Employee".

Here's what I do when I set out to minimize the amount of ViewState used by my page.  I [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx) on the page.  The trace output is added to the bottom of your page when its rendered in the browser.  The trace output identifies every single server control on your page and includes how much ViewState (measured in bytes, I believe) each control stores.  I use this information to calculate when I want to trade the overhead of ViewState for the overhead of recalculating values.

In my previous example, I would elect to recalculate the Label's Text property on every PostBack and stop storing the Text property in ViewState.  This is how my updated markup would look:

```
<asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text="Update this Employee" EnableViewState="false" />
```

And my updated Page_Load event:

```
If myEmployeeObject.IsNew Then TitleLabel.Text = "Create a new Employee"
```

Answer (score 1):

Only time you should use viewstate is when you need to get the value of that sucker back on a postback or something. So for the label example you'd only need viewstate enabled if you had code that said something like

```
void Button1_Click()
{
   label1.text += " more!";
}
```

without viewstate the postback couldn't figure out the contents of the label and you'd just get " more!" over and over with no append. try it.

Really, our the rule of thumb at my office is just turn it off at the page level and then enable it as you need it.

Comment: not so.  Things that are added in the markup <asp:Lable Text="give me" runat=server /> don't need the viewstate to be available in a postback.

Answer (score 1):

First understand the view state, here is a [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) entry that might help.
Start developing your pages by disabling the viewstate at the page level. Most controls in asp .net 2.0 save state required for their functioning in the Control State thus disabling view state would not affect most controls.

For controls that do save data bound to them in the view state like List box, you can avoid the data from landing in the view state (which works fine for most use cases) by doing your binding on the PreInit event.

Other than that, if you don't have a third party control that needs it or so, the performance penalty you encur from using the view state far outweighs the promised preservation of state you get between postbacks.

And finally use tools that help you see the bytes going on in your page's view state.  The ASP.NET View State helper and an add in into Fiddler which shows viewstate data would help you a lot in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

only enableviewstate when you want to preserve the values across http requests, other than that keep it = false. also you dont have to enableviewstate to use a control.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a control  on which the contents will be important (like a text box or drop list) you want to enable viewstate so that the content will available and update to date on a postback.

Anytype of control which outputs somewhat static text (stuff you are not getting back from the user) typically will not have viewstate enable.  This minimizes the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you understand the ViewState better.  No blanket statement like "only enable the ViewState if you have to" will really make sense unless you do.  Understand when the viewstate gets loaded/saved/dirtied.

[here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetviewstatepagecycle.aspx) one of the better articles i've seen

Comment: and another good one - http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I can't think of any time you would want viewstate set to true for label controls.  Its a quick way to make your [w3wp.exe take up hoards of memory](http://blog.whitesites.com/w3wp-exe-using-too-much-memory-and-resources__633900106668026886_blog.htm).

Comment: Labels whose properties are calculated dynamically.